# Wildfly docker image ERROR [io.undertow.request] UT005023: Exception handling request to /app1/ Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.io.File

Tags: java, docker, struts2, wildfly, xwork

We have built an docker image of Wildfly jboss server and deploying the war file on the same. while running the image, deployment of war is getting successful without any error, but while hitting the url on the runtime name it is throwing an exception error as below:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /app1/: Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.io.File
File: File.java
Method: <init>
Line: 421 - java/io/File.java:421:-1
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:111)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:97)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:80)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.forceInit(ManagedFilter.java:125)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain.forceInit(ServletChain.java:126)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.io.File
File: File.java
Method: <init>
Line: 421 - java/io/File.java:421:-1
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - Class: java.io.File
File: File.java
Method: <init>
Line: 421 - java/io/File.java:421:-1
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:958)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:421)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JBossFileRevision.build(JBossFileRevision.java:23)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.monitorFile(DefaultFileManager.java:101)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.loadFile(DefaultFileManager.java:76)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:943)
        ... 56 more
```

When I am deploying the war package to the local system (windows using the wildfly windows installer) it is working fine. but when deployed as docker image giving this error.

here is the dockerfile:

```
#Official base image from docker hub
FROM alpine:latest

#Selecting root user
USER root

#Download wildfly and configure
RUN apk update && apk add wget && mkdir -p /opt/jboss && cd /opt/jboss && wget https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/23.0.2.Final/wildfly-preview-23.0.2.Final.tar.gz && tar -zxvf wildfly-preview-23.0.2.Final.tar.gz && rm -f wildfly-preview-23.0.2.Final.tar.gz && mv wildfly-preview-23.0.2.Final wildfly && adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" jboss && chown -R jboss:jboss /opt/jboss && chmod -R 755 /opt/jboss/


RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
COPY app1.properties /eipliteapps/domains/common/properties/app1.properties

RUN java -version && which java

#Create an application directory for keeping all app1 related files
RUN mkdir -p /app1 && chown -R jboss:jboss /app1 && chown -R jboss:jboss /eipliteapps

#Changing user to Jboss
USER jboss

#Exposing below ports
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9990

#Copy both packages to the application directory
COPY APP1-GUI/target/APP1-GUI-1.0.0-local.war /app1/app1.war
COPY APP1Integration/target/APP1OMIntegration-1.0.0-local.war /app1/APP1OMIntegration.war

#Add customization directory to wildfly server
ADD customization /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/

#Copying required jar and configuration files to wildfly server
COPY customization/ojdbc8.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/

#Execute wildfly customization script
RUN sleep 20 && \
    /bin/sh -x /opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/wildfly_customization.sh
```

Here is the customization.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: execute.sh [WildFly mode] [configuration file]
#
# The default mode is 'standalone' and default configuration is based on the
# mode. It can be 'standalone.xml' or 'domain.xml'.

echo "=> Executing Customization script"


JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly
JBOSS_CLI=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh
JBOSS_MODE=${1:-"standalone"}
JBOSS_CONFIG=${2:-"$JBOSS_MODE.xml"}

echo "JBOSS_HOME  : " $JBOSS_HOME
echo "JBOSS_CLI   : " $JBOSS_CLI
echo "JBOSS_MODE  : " $JBOSS_MODE
echo "JBOSS_CONFIG: " $JBOSS_CONFIG

echo "=> Adding a user"
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh admin --silent

sleep 20
echo "=> Starting WildFly"
echo $JBOSS_HOME/bin/$JBOSS_MODE.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c $JBOSS_CONFIG &
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/$JBOSS_MODE.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c $JBOSS_CONFIG &
sleep 30

echo "=> Executing the commands"
$JBOSS_CLI -c --file=/opt/jboss/wildfly/customization/commands.cli


# Deploy the WAR
mv /app1/app1.war $JBOSS_HOME/$JBOSS_MODE/deployments/app1.war
mv /app1/app1OMIntegration.war $JBOSS_HOME/$JBOSS_MODE/deployments/app1OMIntegration.war
```

The main issue is it is working fine from other systems once deployed, but when deployed again getting the same issue. Application is running on JDK8. In case more info required to troubleshoot please let me know.

Please help in getting this issue resolve.